# How to make the MaxValue of the slider dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and i am struck in a problem. I want to change the max value of the slider depending upon the radio type value.

This is my HTML

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="maxValue" value="100">100
<input type="radio" ng-model="maxValue" value="200">200
<input type="radio" ng-model="maxValue" value="300">300
<br>{{maxValue}}
<br>

<div class="bg-master m-b-10"  id="slider-tooltips" nouislider="" /></div>
```

And below is my directive

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('nouislider', function($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                var newVal = $rootScope.maxValue;

                $(element).noUiSlider({
                    start: 0,
                    step : 1,
                    connect: "lower",
                    range: {
                        'min': 0,
                        'max': newVal
                    }
                    });
                    $(element).Link('lower').to('-inline-<div class="tooltip fade top in" style="top: -33px;left: -14px;opacity: 0.7;" />', 
                        function(value) {
                            $(this).html(
                                '<div class="tooltip-inner">' +
                                '<span>' + value + '</span>' +
                                '</div>'
                            );
                        });
                    $( "#slider-test_1" ).noUiSlider( options, true /* Allow destruction + rebuilding */ );

            }
        };
    });
```

Am binding the maxValue from the radio type to the rootScope and trying to fetch, but the new value is not reflecting in the view. How to change the MaxValue based on radio type.

Need help and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You were creating the attribute. You can use this code to achieve your objective

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input type="radio" ng-model="maxValue" value="100">100
<input type="radio" ng-model="maxValue" value="200">200
<input type="radio" ng-model="maxValue" value="300">300
<br>your model value {{maxValue}}
<br>

<nouislider class="bg-master m-b-10"  id="slider-tooltips" max-value="maxValue">
  directive value {{value}}
</nouislider>
  </body>

</html>


    // app.js
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'World';
      $scope.maxValue = "0";
    });

    app.directive('nouislider',['$parse', function($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope:{
                 'value': "=maxValue"
                },
                link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                    var newVal = $scope.value;
                }
            };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working plunker with an input to set the max value of your slider : https://plnkr.co/edit/yG140JyI9tZsFdfskXl2?p=preview

The problem in your code is that you **never update the option** of your slider, i believe there are better ways to do it than to use a watcher as I did. In your case you should bind a *ng-click* or *ng-change* on your checkboxes, and update your options there.

Should probably be something like :

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="maxValue" ng-change="updateOption()" value="100">100
<input type="radio" ng-model="maxValue" ng-change="updateOption()" value="200">200

scope.updateOption = function() { 
      scope.options = {
      start: scope.start,
      min: scope.min,
      max: scope.maxValue
    };
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: The problem here is i want to re-render the noUiSlider element on change of the MaxValue.. So your answer is not working..

Comment: I don't understand what is not working on my answer, the slider updates to the maxvalue every time. Just use the arrows on the input. Or maybe i don't understand what kind of "re render" you want.